# Files rendering adding ".x95527" before file extension

Tags: permalinks

I migrate my wordpress website from a godaddy hosting to a vultr vps.
I followed this tutorial: https://www.vultr.com/docs/migrate-your-wordpress-site-from-a-shared-host-to-vultr

I have the problem that all the images are rendering with ".x95527" before the extension.

[image: console log]

Comment: Have you considered simply searching for and replacing it with an empty string?